# Model's outputs from a sigmoid function are almost equal to 0.5 and remain unchanged

Tags: python, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch, artificial-intelligence

So I've been training Inception-Resnet V2 on a binary image classification problem and while training I have observed that the logits do not converge either to a 0 or a 1. They just keep fluctuating around 0.5. What may seem to be the error? I am training the pretrained model for 4 epochs on a highly imbalanced dataset which is why I am also using a weighted random sampler. The batch size is 128 and the optimizer is adam with a learning rate of 0.001

````
device = "cuda"


epochs=4
print("======== Training for ", epochs, "epochs=============")
for epoch in range(epochs):
    total_loss = 0
    model.train()
    print("Training.......")
    print("======== EPOCH #",epoch,"=================")
    tmp_acc = 0
    for i,batch in enumerate(train_loader):
        
        img,label = batch["images"],batch["labels"] 
        
        label = label.type(torch.FloatTensor)
        
        img,label = img.to(device),label.to(device)
        model.zero_grad()
        
        op,aux = model(img)
        
        label_cpu = label.cpu().numpy()
        
        op = F.sigmoid(op)
        
        
        output = op.detach().cpu().numpy()
        tmp_acc += accuracy_score(output,label_cpu)
        loss = criterion(op,label)
        total_loss = loss.item()
        loss.backward()
        
        adam.step()
        if(i%10==0 and i>0):
            print("STEP: ",i, "of steps ",len(train_loader))
        
            print("Current loss: ",total_loss/i)
            print("Training Accuracy ",tmp_acc/i)
            print("OP",op)
            print("Label",label_cpu)
        
        
        
    avg_loss = total_loss/len(train_loader)
    print("The loss after ",epoch," epochs is ",avg_loss)
    
    model.eval()
    print("Validating.....")
    tmp_accuracy = 0
    z_count,o_count=0,0
    z_count_truth,o_count_truth = 0,0
    
    for i,batch in enumerate(val_loader):
        img,label = batch["images"],batch["labels"]
        img = img.to(device)
        with torch.no_grad():
            op = F.sigmoid(model(img))
        op_cpu = op.detach().cpu().numpy()
        label = label.numpy()
        tmp_accuracy += accuracy_score(op_cpu,label)
        z_count += np.sum(op_cpu==0)
        o_count += np.sum(op_cpu==1)
        z_count_truth += np.sum(label==0)
        o_count_truth += np.sum(label==1)
    percent_correct_z = z_count/z_count_truth
    percent_correct_o = o_count/o_count_truth
    accuracy = tmp_accuracy/len(val_loader)
    print("Accuracy: ", "is ",accuracy)
    #print("Percent of correct zero labels ",percent_correct_z)
    #print("Percent of correct one labels ",percent_correct_o)```
````

The output looks like

```
STEP:  90 of steps  99
Current loss:  0.007694996065563626
Training Accuracy  0.5019965277777778
OP tensor([[0.4962],
        [0.4956],
        [0.4950],
        [0.4957],
        [0.4945],
        [0.4957],
        [0.4952],
        [0.4965],
        [0.4950],
        [0.4962],
        [0.4956],
        [0.4956],
        [0.4951],
        [0.4953],
        [0.4956],
        [0.4958],
        [0.4949],
        [0.4945],
        [0.4955],
        [0.4924],
        [0.4952],
        [0.4952],
        [0.4958],
        [0.4953],
        [0.4959],
        [0.4952],
        [0.4965],
        [0.4956],
        [0.4956],
        [0.4381],
        [0.4951],
        [0.4946],
        [0.4957],
        [0.4951],
        [0.4955],
        [0.4952],
        [0.4955],
        [0.4948],
        [0.4951],
        [0.4960],
        [0.4956],
        [0.4955],
        [0.4958],
        [0.4957],
        [0.4953],
        [0.4954],
        [0.4955],
        [0.4959],
        [0.4949],
        [0.4960],
        [0.4953],
        [0.4949],
        [0.4951],
        [0.4952],
        [0.4949],
        [0.4954],
        [0.4956],
        [0.4951],
        [0.4947],
        [0.4958],
        [0.4953],
        [0.4960],
        [0.4959],
        [0.4958],
        [0.4948],
        [0.4947],
        [0.4957],
        [0.4961],
        [0.4955],
        [0.4959],
        [0.4955],
        [0.4954],
        [0.4959],
        [0.4952],
        [0.4955],
        [0.4951],
        [0.4962],
        [0.4961],
        [0.4961],
        [0.4960],
        [0.4956],
        [0.4959],
        [0.4953],
        [0.4960],
        [0.4955],
        [0.4949],
        [0.4958],
        [0.4953],
        [0.4955],
        [0.4959],
        [0.4951],
        [0.4961],
        [0.4939],
        [0.4954],
        [0.4953],
        [0.4958],
        [0.4953],
        [0.4949],
        [0.4959],
        [0.4958],
        [0.4960],
        [0.4949],
        [0.4957],
        [0.4964],
        [0.4949],
        [0.4956],
        [0.4952],
        [0.4959],
        [0.4954],
        [0.4958],
        [0.4954],
        [0.4951],
        [0.4953],
        [0.4953],
        [0.4958],
        [0.4954],
        [0.4955],
        [0.4954],
        [0.4960],
        [0.4946],
        [0.4950],
        [0.4953],
        [0.4957],
        [0.4956],
        [0.4954],
        [0.4940],
        [0.4951],
        [0.4955]], device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<SigmoidBackward>)
Label [0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0.
 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1.
 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1.
 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0.
 0. 1. 1. 0. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.
 1. 0. 1. 1. 0. 1. 1. 0.]
```

OP Tensor corresponds to the output logits
Label corresponds to the original labels

Comment: 4 epochs is way too little. Try training it for longer, maybe 100 epochs...

Comment: Can you show some of the labels? Are you sure they are either 0 or 1?

Comment: Thanks for all the inputs, the labels have been verified they are properly distributed and only 0 and 1. But I think Ash was right about this since using transforms.CenterCrop was causing the image pixels to go to a range of 0.5-1. Trying with a different transform now

Comment: Also i can train for more epochs but just see the loss, its so low already

Comment: Please take care not to format parts of your text as code (edited).

Answer (score 0):

Since you have

```
op = F.sigmoid(op)
```

and all the output values are around `0.5`, it seems to follow from the definition of the sigmoid function that all its input values are very close to `0`. This means that it's very likely that either all your input images are zero or that the weights of the network are not initialized properly. Since resnet v2 has a lot of skip connections, it seems more probable that the problem comes from your input images.

As a general initial test, it's often useful to see if your network is capable of overfitting a very small dataset. In your case I'd try to overfit a single image to its label first, that will make debugging much easier than with your current batchsize and shuffling.

Comment: Is it because I am normalizing the images and they are in the range of 0-1? Would that be causing the problem?

Comment: @NoobC0der No that shouldn't be the problem at all. If the input to the sigmoid is 0 everywhere though, there should be some sort of bug happening somewhere, I'd suggest checking (if possible visualizing) input/output values layer by layer. How are the weight models initialised?

Comment: It could also be that your data is too difficult for the problem you have. Each gradient update is essentially random, and so it keeps going back and forth and doesn't take your weights significantly far away from 0.